# How to take data in google sheet script via POST request in JSON format?

Tags: post, google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-post

This question is about receiving POST request from somewhere. I'm looking for a google sheet script function that can take and handle data from the POST request in JSON format. Could you suggest any example?

The POST request is here:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/BOdirjv45Dn6FHrx_4GUguuS6NJxnSEeviMHm3HerJl4UsDBnDgfFPO/

{
  "p1": "writeTitle",
  "p2": [[URL]],
  "p3": [[PIC_A]],
  "p4": [[PIC_B]],
  "p5": [[TITLE]]
}

application/json
```

`doPost()` doesn't work:

```
doPost(e) {
var json = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
Logger.log(json);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script make HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742350/google-apps-script-make-http-post)

Comment: Apps Script has the reserved functions names `doGet()` and `doPost()` which are event listeners for GET and POST requests made to the published Url of an Apps Script Web App.  You can publish a script as an Apps Script Web App that is bound to a Google Sheet. (Or Doc or Form)  So, to get code to run from a POST request made from some external source, you need to create a `doPost(e)` function.  The parameter `e` will receive the payload object from the POST request.  See "Event Objects" in the Apps Script documentation.

Comment: @Sandy Good, thank you! I still don't understand how can I get access to sent data? I did doPost(e) { var json = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  Logger.log(json); } and it shows nothing.

Comment: Log the value of `e` -  `Logger.log(typeof e)`  `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))`  Also, you must publish the script as a Web App **EVERY** time that you make a change to the code.

Comment: @Sandy Good, thank you very much! I added JSON.stringify to my initial json before sending a POST request and it works. But when I try to log Logger.log(typeof e) I see: "No logs found. Use Logger API to add logs to your project."

Comment: @I'-'I, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the value from the request body as an object.
- You have already deployed Web Apps.

If my understanding of your situation is correct, how about this modification?

### Post and retrieved object:

As a sample, I used the following curl command to POST to Web Apps.

```
curl -L \
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
-d '{"p1": "writeTitle","p2": "[[URL]]","p3": "[[PIC_A]]","p4": "[[PIC_B]]","p5": "[[TITLE]]"}' \
"https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec"
```

When above command is run, `e` of `doPost(e)` is as follows.

```
{
  "parameter": {},
  "contextPath": "",
  "contentLength": 90,
  "queryString": "",
  "parameters": {},
  "postData": {
    "type": "application/json",
    "length": 90,
    "contents": "{\"p1\": \"writeTitle\",\"p2\": \"[[URL]]\",\"p3\": \"[[PIC_A]]\",\"p4\": \"[[PIC_B]]\",\"p5\": \"[[TITLE]]\"}",
    "name": "postData"
  }
}
```

The posted payload can be retrieved by `e.postData`. From above response, it is found that the value you want can be retrieved by `e.postData.contents`. By the way, when the query parameter and the payload are given like as follows,

```
curl -L \
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
-d '{"p1": "writeTitle","p2": "[[URL]]","p3": "[[PIC_A]]","p4": "[[PIC_B]]","p5": "[[TITLE]]"}' \
"https://script.google.com/macros/s/#####/exec?key=value"
```

`value` can be retrieved by `e.parameter` or `e.parameters`. And the payload can be retrieved by `e.postData.contents`.

### Modified script:

In this modified script, the result can be seen at the Stackdriver, and also the result is returned.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var json = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  console.log(json);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(json));
}
```

### Note:

- When you modified your script of Web Apps, please redeploy it as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. This is an important point.

### Reference:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Stackdriver Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much! I added JSON.stringify to my initial json before sending a POST request and it works. I can get back this data using doPost function. But I still can't see the log: console.log(json); does not show anything.

Comment: No logs found. Use Logger API to add logs to your project.

Comment: @Neret Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved. You can see the official document of Stackdriver at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#using_stackdriver_logging).

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you for your support.