# How can I use Google Apps Script in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to get data in Google sheet to Unity. I will use Apps script of Google. I want to send the ID value and get the related row. I want to know the related method. And I use doPost(e), I wonder to know the value of Parameter of doPost. How can know it?

I tried to return the parameter using "ContentService". But its output is [object Object].

Comment: Is this information useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53008348 and https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#event-object-of-web-apps